# Assigning a value to a column derived from another column in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with three columns containing text. One column (column1) consists of 3 unique entries; "H", "D", "A".

I want to create a new column with the entries from the other two columns (column2 & column3) based on the entry from the column containing "H", "D" or "A".

I tried to write a function:

```
def func(x):
   if x== "H":
        return column2
   elif x == "A":
        return column3
   else:
        return "D"
```

I then tried to use the `.apply()` function:

`df["new_col"] = df["column1"].apply(func)`

But this doesn't work as it doesn't recognise column2 & column 3. How do I access the entries of the columns column2 & column 3 inside the function?

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You can send the whole row to the function and access it's columns:

```
def func(x):
   if x["column1"]== "H":
        return x["column2"]
   elif x["column1"] == "A":
        return x["column3"]
   else:
        return "D"

df["new_col"] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `.apply` you can use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to choose elements based upon the conditions:

Consider the example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column1': ['H', 'D', 'A', 'H', 'A'],
    'column2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'column3': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
})
```

Use:

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [
    df['column1'].eq('H'), 
    df['column1'].eq('A')
]

choices = [
    df['column2'], 
    df['column3']]

df['new_col'] = np.select(
    conditions, choices, default='D')
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

  column1  column2  column3 new_col
0       H        1       10       1
1       D        2       20       D
2       A        3       30      30
3       H        4       40       4
4       A        5       50      50
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your query, I'll illustrate taking your example.

Conisder this data frame:

```py
d = {
    "col1": ["H","D","A","H","D","A"],
    "col2": [172,180,190,156,176,182],
    "col3":[80,75,53,80,100,92]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

df

```
  col1  col2    col3
0   H   172     80
1   D   180     75
2   A   190     53
3   H   156     80
4   D   176     100
5   A   182     92
```

apply takes in a Series object and accesses the columns using appropriate indices with respect to the dataframe you passed. On calling apply it is necessary to pass axis=1 , since you you need column values for each row. Finally append the returned series to the original dataframe.

```py
def func(df):
    if df[0] == 'H':
        return df[1]
    elif df[0] == 'A':
        return df[2]
    else:
        return "D"

df['col4'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

df

```
  col1  col2    col3    col4
0   H   172     80      172
1   D   180     75      D
2   A   190     53      53
3   H   156     80      156
4   D   176     100     D
5   A   182     92      92
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am retrieving the rows with the conditions required and altering corresponding rows in `column4`. We can achieve this using `iloc` in a `pandas dataframe`.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"column1":["H","D","A","D", "H", "H", "A"],"column2":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],"column3":[12,23,34,45,56,67,87]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df["column4"] = None

df.iloc[list(df[df["column1"] == "H"].index), 3] = df[df["column1"] == "H"]["column2"]
df.iloc[list(df[df["column1"] == "A"].index), 3] = df[df["column1"] == "A"]["column3"]
df.iloc[list(df[df["column4"].isnull()].index), 3] = "D"
```

The output of the above processing is given below,

```
print(df)

  column1  column2  column3 column4
0       H        1       12       1
1       D        2       23       D
2       A        3       34      34
3       D        4       45       D
4       H        5       56       5
5       H        6       67       6
6       A        7       87      87
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.select() function

```
import numpy as np
df['column4'] = np.select([df.column1=='H',df.column1=='A'],
                           [df.column2,df.column3], default = 'D')
```

It's a kind of a case when statement in which 1st argument is a values to compare,2nd argument is the output corresponding to that comparison. Default is a keyword argument fot the 'else' statement.